# How to pass arguments to `:map gx <Plug>(SomeFunction)`?

Tags: vimscript, map-operator

### Context

I'm evaluating https://github.com/tyru/open-browser.vim which looks really promising.

I figured out how to set the default search engine and add a mapping

```
" vim-openbrowser
let g:openbrowser_default_search = 'duckduckgo'
let g:netrw_nogx = 1 " disable netrw's gx mapping.
nmap gx <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
vmap gx <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
```

The docs also state that you can pick one of a dozen search engines, like github

`:OpenBrowserSmartSearch -github  <stuff to search here>`

### Problem

How to I pass the `-github` engine argument to `<Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)`?

These haven't worked - and I'm plain guessing at them:

```
nmap gG <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search) -github
nmap gG <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search -github)

nmap gG <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search, github)
nmap gG <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search, -github)
```

Comment: You'll have to create a mapping to `:<C-u>call openbrowser#_cmd_smart_search('-github')<CR>` but I'm not entirely sure it will work as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (as far as I know) "proper" way to provide an argument to `<Plug>` mappings.

`<Plug>` is a convenience mapping to some functionality exposed by a plugin.
User of a plugin has to remap it to preferred keys like you did.

So your only option is to either check the documentation for the "real" code behind exposed `<Plug>` or check the source code of a plugin to find it out.

Once you know what is mapped to `<Plug>` it should be clear whether it is possible to provide additional argument to the command/func behind it.

In your case if you look into the source code of a plugin you can see https://github.com/tyru/open-browser.vim/blob/master/plugin/openbrowser.vim#L56-L57 :

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search) :<C-u>call openbrowser#_keymap_smart_search('n')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search) :<C-u>call openbrowser#_keymap_smart_search('v')<CR>
```

Where `openbrowser#_keymap_smart_search` accepts variable number of arguments https://github.com/tyru/open-browser.vim/blob/80ec3f2bb0a86ac13c998e2f2c86e16e6d2f20bb/autoload/openbrowser.vim#L61-L64 :

```
" <Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search)
function! openbrowser#_keymap_smart_search(...) abort
  return call(s:OpenBrowser.keymap_smart_search, a:000, s:OpenBrowser)
endfunction
```

So I guess (didn't test it) you can try following mappings:

```
nnoremap <silent> gG :<C-u>call openbrowser#_keymap_smart_search('n', '-github')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> gG :<C-u>call openbrowser#_keymap_smart_search('v', '-github')<CR>
```

### UPD

And they didn't work...

Looks like it uses `vital` "module" which is hard to follow.

Anyway, according to the documentation you can use buffer local variable to set up default search `b:openbrowser_default_search`:

```
nmap gG :let b:openbrowser_default_search = 'github'<CR><Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search):unlet b:openbrowser_default_search<CR>
vmap gG :<c-u>let b:openbrowser_default_search = 'github'<CR>gv<Plug>(openbrowser-smart-search):unlet b:openbrowser_default_search<CR>
```

For normal mode map it:

1. setups `b:openbrowser_default_search` to be `github`
2. proceeds with what is behind `<Plug>` mapping
3. deletes `b:openbrowser_default_search`

For visual and select mode maps it:

1. removes visual selection with `<c-u>` (otherwise next `:let` wouldn't work)
2. setups `b:openbrowser_default_search` to be `github`
3. reselects visual with `gv`
4. proceeds with what is behind `<Plug>` mapping
5. deletes `b:openbrowser_default_search`